# When training a LSTM Autoencoder on time-series data, what tells the model that it is operating on split windows of the same signal?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, autoencoder

I'm working with LSTM Autoencoders and my goal is to train my model to reconstruct a given signal. My signal is split into windows because my model has to operate online and I was wondering how can the LSTM layer understand that it is receiving the signal from [x,x+window_width], with x as the initial timestep and window_width the window width. Can anyone explain it to me?

Example. Let's take a signal [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] and divide it into windows of width of 5, so [1,2,3,4,5] ,[ 2,3,4,5,6],...,[7,8,9,10,11].

when i have to set the input shape i will write input_shape=(6,5,1)

So how can the model know if the 6 batches are independent signals or multiple parts of the same signal? In my opinion the only way is to add a new feature that tells the timestep of each element (like [[7,6],[8,7],[9,8],[10,9],[11,10 ] ]) or to set a different index for each window.